# Shiny - How to test fileInput()

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to write tests in order to check if a shiny function `fileInput()` is reading files correctly.
My problem is that I don't know what to write in `session$setInputs()` in order to grab the file from my system.

Here is an example app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagList(
    fileInput("file", "Please upload a file"),
    tableOutput("text")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  file <- reactive({input$file})
  
  output$text <- renderTable({
    req(file())
    read.csv(file()$datapath)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now, I want to be able to use `testServer()` in order to set a file address and see if my app loads it correctly, but I can't figure out how to do it:

```
address <- "path/to/text.csv"

testServer(server, {
  session$setInputs(file = address)
  print(file())
})
```

I think it has to do with the fact that `fileInput()` uploads the file to a temp folder and returns to shiny a dataframe where you can get the datapath, but I'm unable to simulate this pass in order to make the test work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering this late.
I asked the same question at rstudio's forums and got an answer [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/test-fileinput-with-testserver/105272)

The basics of it are setting the file's datapath as a list:

```
address <- "path/to/text.csv"

testServer(server, {   session$setInputs(file= list(datapath = address)) })
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question as you do, I did some investigating and could not find any way of testing fileInput with testServer or testthat. The best solution that I found was testing fileInput by taking a snapshot when recording a test with recordTest() of the shinytest package.